# Equation with the big O notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation, asymptotics

How I can prove equality below?

$$
\frac{1}{1 + O(n^{-1})} = 1 + O({n^{-1}}),
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we are considering situation when $n \to \infty$.

It is clearly that it is true. But I don't know which property I have to use to prove it formally. I will appreciate if someone could give me some clues.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had stated why you think that the statement is clearly true. Possibly the reason could have been made into a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that
$$
f(n)=1+{\mathcal O}(n^{-1}),
$$
iff
$$
|f(n)-1|\le cn^{-1},
$$
for some $c>0$ and for $n\ge n\ge N$. Thus 
$$
1-cn^{-1}\le f(n)\le 1+cn^{-1},
$$
for $n\ge N$ and hence for $n\ge N$:
$$
1-\frac{c}{n+c}=\frac{n}{n+c}=\frac{1}{1+cn^{-1}}\le \frac{1}{f(n)}\le \frac{1}{1-cn^{-1}}=\frac{n}{n-c}=1+\frac{c}{n-c},
$$
and hence
$$
\left|\frac{1}{f(n)}-1\,\right|\le \max\left\{\frac{c}{n-c},\frac{c}{n+c}\right\}=\frac{c}{n-c}\le \frac{2c}{n},
$$
if $n\ge \max\{N,2c\}$.

Thus $1/f=1+{\mathcal O}(n^{-1})$.

Answer (score 3):

If $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $O(\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow 0$ and using $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n} \ \ \ \ , \ \ |z|<1$$ we have $$\frac{1}{1 + O(n^{-1})} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}O(\frac{1}{n})^{k} = 1 +O(\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: I think this is sufficient.

Comment: Generally, infinite sums of big-Ohs should not be simplified under the assumption that the implied constants are uniform (they may well be in this case, but that information is not carried by the notation).  It would be better style to use the uniform convergence of the power series on compact subsets to first obtain $1/(1-z) = 1 + z + O(z^2)$ for $|z| < 1/2$, so that you only combine finitely many big-Oh terms.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f\in O(n^{-1})$. Then there exists $c\in\mathbb R$ and $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that  $|f(n)|<\frac cn$ for all $n>n_0$. Wlog. $n_0>2c$. Then for $n>n_0$ we have $1+f(n)>1-\frac cn>1-\frac c{n_0}>\frac12$ and hence 
$$ 0<\frac1{1+f(n)}<\frac1{1-\frac cn}=1-\frac{c}{n-c}$$
and  from $-\frac c{n-c}\in O(n^{-1})$ the claim.

Comment: Don't you need a lower bound for $1/(1+f(n))$ as well? (A lower bound that is $1+O(1/n)$, I mean.)